# Control Slider Pips through the Select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider-pips

I want to control  the slider through it's handles as well as the Select list. Can't figure out how to link them both together. I'm using jQuery-ui and jQuery UI Pips.js

Here is my code so far:

HTML:

```
<div id="awesome2"><div>
<div id = "selector">
    <select  id = "num" onclick = "setNum();">
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

And here is JS:

```js
function setNum() {
  var num = document.getElementById("num").value;
  //some other function to apply in here ...
}

var min = 1;
var max = 5;

$("document").ready(function() {
  var $awesome2 = $("#awesome2").slider({
    max: max,
    step: 1,
    min: min
  });
  $awesome2.slider("pips", {
    rest: "label"
  }).slider("float");
  setNum();
});
```

For some reason function `setNum();` doesn't work when I call it from the slider, and the Select list is not linked to the slider.

As a final result I want to be able to get control of the slider through the Select list and a slider, e.g. if I choose the value from the Select list the slider picks up this value and moves slider to that position, and vice versa, if I move the slider manually the value passed to the Select list. If it makes sense.

I spent good 4 hours to figure out what is wrong, but still no luck. 
Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: *"For some reason function setNum(); doesn't work when I call it from the slider"* - How are you calling it *from the slider*? what do you mean it doesn't work? It doesn't seem to have any code that does any *work*. Then how do you expect it to work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply T J, deeper digging into the api docs shows that this library doesn't support that feature ...

Answer (score 0):

use the code:

```
$("$awesome2")
   .slider( "option", "value", document.getElementById("num").value );
```

This allows you to change the internal value of the slider, and jQuery Slider Pips will automatically update it's styling to reflect this option :)

http://jsfiddle.net/fqxebdye/